# Mac QuickTime Player Icon Shrunk

Tags: macos, mac, icon

Very weird my QuickTime Player Icon just Shrunk. How can I get it back to normal Please?

[image]

Also This is what it looks like even when magnification mode is turn on for the dock.

[image]

Comment: @FabianGr the OP [knows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5178841/hunter) how the accept system works, you don't need to remind them of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart your Mac system. this should fix the problem.

Comment: As would killing the stuck QTP process through Finder or Terminal